# html table row expandable

Tags: jquery, html

I have an html table, and its row is already expandable,
but what I want is to expand only one row.

When a row is expanded and the user expands another row, I want the expanded row to be closed. So, in short, only one row can be expanded. I tried searching for a solution but I can't find one. Maybe I don't know the keyword to use.

This is my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#report tr:odd").addClass("odd");
            $("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
            $("#report tr:first-child").show();

            $("#report tr.odd").click(function(){

                $(this).next("tr").toggle();
                $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus-sign').toggleClass('glyphicon-minus-sign');
            });

        });
```

this is the example code
https://jsfiddle.net/knowmeifyou/bc6c8ab1/

what i want is only one row can be expanded. thank you

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: this is the example code https://jsfiddle.net/knowmeifyou/bc6c8ab1/

what i want is only one row can be expanded. thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

One general trick people do in this situation, at least before React & Co. came along, is to save the state into the DOM through some attribute like a class. For example, in your case, you can mark a row as `expanded` by adding a class to it and simple close all currently `expanded` rows before expanding new one.

Replace the click handler code with this:

```
$("#report tr.odd").click(function(){
  $('.expanded').each(function() {
    var $row = $(this);
    toggle($row);
    $row.removeClass('expanded');
  });

  var $currentRow = $(this);
  toggle($currentRow);
  $currentRow.addClass('expanded');
});

function toggle($row) {
  $row.next("tr").toggle();
  $row.find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus-sign').toggleClass('glyphicon-minus-sign');
 }
```

Comment: change the whole code for expanding table row to the code above sir? i tried it. but now all the html table row collapsed on page load without user interaction

Comment: @knowmeifyou https://jsfiddle.net/limdauto/frj805j8/1/ fiddle. And please, no sir..

Comment: sorry for calling you 'sir' we use to call a person like that to show respect.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your issue , Just replace the following jQuery code :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#report tr:odd").addClass("odd");
    $("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
    $("#report tr:first-child").show();

    $("#report tr.odd").click(function(){
        $("#report tr.odd").next("tr").hide();
        $(this).next("tr").toggle();
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus-sign').toggleClass('glyphicon-minus-sign');
    });
});
```

I have added `$("#report tr.odd").next("tr").hide();` in the code.

It may help you.